# extern keyword and setting string variables

Tags: c, string, extern

I have a struct declared as `extern conf_t conf`.

```
typedef struct {
    int     home_dir_len;
    char        *home_dir;
    int     key_file_len;
    char        *key_file;
    unsigned int    max_mem;
    unsigned int    runtime;
} conf_t;
```

I am trying to set its variables through the function below, however only the integer values are being set, not the strings.

```
if (strcmp(tok1, "HOME_DIR") == 0) {
    char *dir = strtok(NULL, &delim);
    conf.home_dir_len = strlen(dir);
    conf.home_dir = dir;
}
else if (strcmp(tok1, "KEY_FILE") ==0) {
    char *key = strtok(NULL, &delim);
    conf.key_file_len = strlen(key);
    conf.key_file = calloc(conf.key_file_len +1, sizeof(char));
    conf.key_file = key;
}
else if (strcmp(tok1, "MAX_MEM") ==0) {
    conf.max_mem = atoi(strtok(NULL, &delim));
}
else if (strcmp(tok1, "RUNTIME") ==0) {
    conf.runtime = atoi(strtok(NULL, &delim));
}
else {
    perror("you shouldnt be here");
}
```

This is the output:

> ```
> conf.home_dir_len = 5
> conf.home_dir = ' and more empty lines
> '   **This should be /tmp/**
> conf.key_file_len = 10
> conf.key_file = 'nd more empty lines
> '  **this should be myfile.key**
> conf.max_mem = 10
> conf.runtime = 10
> ```

Can you please explain why and how can I correct it?

Comment: You haven't really shown enough context here.  What's the definition of the structure?  At a minimum, you are leaking the result of the `calloc` call.  And `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: how can i edit my code to not do that, i added the calloc for the second part to see if it made a difference, but it didnt as they both are still incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each `if(condition)` where you perform a `char *` assignment, it is evident that the string `strtok()` is processing is only a temporary available for referencing.  You need to form a copy of the string for your structure.  You partially did that (you allocated data, but did not copy the string) in `conf.key_file =` but missed it in  `conf.home_dir =`.  Recommend:

```
// delete  conf.home_dir = dir;
conf.home_dir = strdup(dir);
...
// delete conf.key_file = calloc(conf.key_file_len +1, sizeof(char));
// delete conf.key_file = key;
conf.key_file = strdup(key);
```

As @Carl Norum pointed out, there needs to be more code.  So although the above idea may solve the issue.  without additional code, it may only be a partial solution.

`strdup(s)` does 3 things.  It allocated enough memory for a copy of `s` into say 's2'.  It copies 's' into `s2`.  It then returns 's2'.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly, I managed to fix it last night but was too late to update it here, i ended up callocing space and then using a strcpy but a strdup is smarter!